# Image doesnt change in javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap an image using jQuery but when I run the page, it seems the `chase()` method completes while the animation is still going. The idea is that the images are replaced with a flipped version so they appear to chase one another back and forth. However, the images appear facing to the left the entire time. The method seems to complete all at once, rather than showing each iteration.

```
<audio controls autoplay="false" onplay="chase()">
  <source src="Links/sillyChase.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<div id="dexter">
    <img id="dex" src="Images/dexterRight.jpg" width="170" height="120"/>
</div>
<div id="deedee">
     <img id="dee" src="Images/deedeeRight.jpg" width="170" height="120"/>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function chase(){
    for(var k=0;k<10;k++){ 
        $("#dex").attr("src","Images/dexterRight.jpg"); 
        $("#dee").attr("src","Images/deedeeRight.jpg"); 

        //moves images right  
        $("#dexter").animate({"left": "+=500px"},"slow"); 
        $("#deedee").animate({"left": "+=500px"},"slow"); 

        $("#dex").attr("src","Images/dexterLeft.jpg");
        $("#dee").attr("src","Images/deedeeLeft.jpg");  

        //moves images left 
        $("#dexter").animate({"left": "-=500px"},"slow"); 
        $("#deedee").animate({"left": "-=500px"},"slow"); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use animate callback function or use promise()

Comment: Someone posted example code that helped me understand your comment, then deleted it....but I understand! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
function chase(){
        for(var k=0;k<10;k++){ 
             $("#dexter,#deedee").promise().done(function() {
                   $("#dex").attr("src","Images/dexterRight.jpg"); 
                   $("#dee").attr("src","Images/deedeeRight.jpg");  
              });

              //moves images right  
              $("#dexter,#deedee").animate({"left": "+=500px"},"slow", function(){
                  $("#dex").attr("src","Images/dexterLeft.jpg");
                  $("#dee").attr("src","Images/deedeeLeft.jpg");
                  $("#dexter,#deedee").animate({"left": "-=500px"},"slow");
              });
        }

    }
```